# Does spring support invoke dynamic for groovy-backed beans?

Tags: spring, groovy, invokedynamic

Is it possible to configure Groovy beans declared with **lang** namespace or manually with **GroovyScriptFactory** in such a way, that they use invoke dynamic support?

```
<lang:groovy id="messenger" script-source="classpath:Messenger.groovy">
```

I have not found any reliable documentation on this case.

And, does a GroovyClassLoader provided with groovy-all:indy maven artifact uses this feature, or it can be used only with groovy compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to activate the invoke-dynamic support, you have to :

1. Use groovy-indy.jar
2. Set the system property `groovy.target.indy` to true or the `CompilerConfiguration.DEFAULT.getOptimizationOptions().put("indy", true)`

This will enable this function for all invocations of the groovy compiler (and Spring will use this option). I don't think there is a way to configure this option through the `ScriptEngine`, for only a subset of scripts.

If you use directly a GroovyClassLoader, you can provide this option through the `CompilerConfiguration.optimizationOptions.indy` property